# Adding nodes to end of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Having trouble adding nodes to the end of a linked 
The code is pretty self explanatory, the addToEnd method adds a single node to the end of a linkedlist.

```
public class ll5 {
    // Private inner class Node

    private class Node{
        int data;
        Node link;

        public Node(int x, Node p){
            data = x;
            link = p;
        }
    }
    // End of Node class

    public Node head;

    public ll5(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void addToEnd(int data) {
        Node p = head;
        while (p.link != null)
            p=p.link;
        p.link=new Node(data, null);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ll5 list = new ll5();

        list.printList();
        System.out.println("How many values do you want to add to the list");
        int toAdd = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < toAdd; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value " + (i + 1));
            list.addToEnd(input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("The list is:");
        list.printList();

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Why is it giving me an NullPointerException error?? The error is somewhere in the while loop in the addToEnd method.

Comment: I guess that `Node p = head` makes `p = null` since `head` is `null` when you call `addToEnd` the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't handled the initial condition when list has nothing and head is null. Because of that you're getting NPE.

Following method should work.

```
public void addToEnd(int data) {
    Node p = head;
    if( p == null) {
        head = new Node(data, null);
    } else {
        while (p.link != null)
            p=p.link;
        p.link=new Node(data, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the head is null at the beginning

```
public ll5(){
    head = null; // <-- head is null
}

public void addToEnd(int data) {
    Node p = head;  //<-- you assigned head, which is null, to p
    while (p.link != null) //<-- p is null, p.link causes NullException
        p=p.link;
    p.link=new Node(data, null);
}
```